# Ошибка в запросе SQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

И так, создал новую таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news_rss` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `kat` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `char` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  unique (url)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

написал простенький обработчки формы:

```
include_once '../inc/conf.php';  
$table = "news_rss";
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не могу создать соединение");
mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['name'])){

 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $url=$_POST['url'];
 $kat=$_POST['kat'];
 $char=$_POST['char'];

$query = "INSERT INTO '$table' (name, url, kat, char) values ('$name', '$url', '$kat', '$char')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();

echo ("<div style=\"text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;\">
<font color=\"green\">Данные успешно сохранены!</font>
 <a href=\"index.html\">Вернуться назад</a></div>");
 }
```

При отправке запроса выдает ошибку:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''news_rss' (name, url, kat, char) values ('Проба', 'ссылка' at line 1

Что делаю не так?

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: таблица не должна быть в таких кавычках (либо без кавычек, либо обратные (на букве ё))

Comment: изменил подключение на такое


$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
$link = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbName);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Ошибка подключения: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


выдает ошибку 

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/arashvg/data/www/...../index.php on line 106

Comment: Подключение ваше было непричем, вам написали что ошибку искать в ковычках названия таблицы.
Если вы захотите перейти на MySQLi(у вас сейчас MySQL) то стоит ознакомится с синтаксисом вызова всех остальных комманд данного расширения, они немного отличаются от вызова комманд из расширения MySQL.

По вашей ошибке:

Было:

    $query = "INSERT INTO '$table' (name, url, kat, char) values ('$name', '$url', '$kat', '$char')";

Надо:

    $query = "INSERT INTO `$table` (name, url, kat, char) values ('$name', '$url', '$kat', '$char')";

Comment: вернул то же подключение, запрос 

<pre>$query = "INSERT INTO $table (name, url, kat, char) values ('$name', '$url', '$kat', '$char')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());</pre>

выдает туже ошибку <pre>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'char) values</pre>

Comment: char - зарезервированное слово, возьмете его в обратные кавычки,

 по поводу mysqli - надо не просто использовать mysqli_connect но и все остальные методы должны быть из mysqli, кроме того я рекомендую использовать prepared statements, т.к. иначе вам придется вычищать переменные получаемые от пользователя.

Comment: Ваша ошибка - в char или ранее по тексту в строковых переменных встречается ковычка('). фильтруйте переменные перед подачей их в базу. 

Было:

    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $url=  $_POST['url'];
    $kat=  $_POST['kat'];
    $char= $_POST['char'];

Стало:

    $name= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $url=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url']);
    $kat=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kat']);
    $char= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['char']);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

char надо взять в апострофы:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO \`$table\` (\`name\`, \`url\`, \`kat\`, \`char\`) values ('$name', '$url', '$kat', '$char')";
```

Comment: и будет ошибка, такой ответ дан в коментариях выше и намного раньше вашего ответа, почитайте коментарии под вопросом)

Comment: не будет ошибки: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7b05/2)

Comment: вчера уже решил данную проблему тем что взял названия полей в обратные кавычки, именно из за этого была ошибка.

Answer (score 2):

```
"INSERT INTO ".$table." (`name`, `url`, `kat`, `char`) values ('$name', '$url', '$kat', '$char')"
```

У вас же $table переменная, MySQL просто не понимает в какую таблицу ему нужно писать.
Ну или так:

```
"INSERT INTO `".$table."` (`name`, `url`, `kat`, `char`) values ('$name', '$url', '$kat', '$char')"
```

Comment: '$name', '$url', '$kat', '$char' - это по вашему значения? ;) все будет хорошо, php подставит значения переменных и без явной конкатенации. а вот обратные кавычки использовать лучше всегда, ну по крайней мере пока не прекратятся попытки использовать зарезервированные слова или кирилицу в качестве имен столбцов и таблиц...

Comment: вчера уже решил данную проблему тем что взял названия полей в обратные кавычки, именно из за этого была ошибка.